# How to show 2 scenes on screen at the same time

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How can I show 2 scenes on the screen at the same time on Sprite Kit Swift?
I need to first scene be placed of the second (I need one scene to be seen and atop of it appeared other scene, which has some sprites).
Or tell me, how developers make, for example, menu (with buttons like "restart", "results") to appear on other scene when player dies? And that time, also you can see the main scene with location (or with dead character)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need 2 scenes. However, you can accomplish what you are after with basing an node tree off of an SKNode. For your menu idea you could build it out of however many objects you'd like, but since it is based from an SKNode, you can animate it to your hearts content. No need for two scene, just build another node tree and animate the root. If that isn't enough answer, I could write some code to help you out if need be. Sorry watching the Netflix and feeling lazy.

Comment: If you will write code, it will be great. )) Show me very simple example please.